# How to use a PHP API

Tags: php, api

There is a really simple API at http://mee.la/api.php, and I was wondering if anyone could help me use it. You can read more about the API at http://mee.la/api-about.php but all it is is a call to http://mee.la/api.php?url=http://test.com/, which returns http://mee.la/2755. I am trying to create a PHP page which when loaded makes said call, and prints the response. Any ideas how I should start because I'm only just starting to learn PHP,

Comment: Use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to call urls from PHP.

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: no need for curl. file_get_contents can open http connections

Comment: @dualed how do you post a json body in `file_get_contents`

Comment: you don't. This api does not seemm to require a POST request

Comment: @DevZer0: with stream_context_create. That said, I think Curl is simpler and a better choice.

Comment: @dualed regardless of this API, i never use `file_get_contents` for API calls, curl gives you more control, the control you need when dealing with APIs

Comment: well, for such a simple api curl is only superior if you are payd either by time or lines of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this, put input box and a form

```
<form action="your_script.php" method="POST">
   <input type="edit" name="address"/>
   <input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

and in PHP use curl to get the URL from the API

```
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mee.la/api.php?url=' . 
        urlencode($_POST['address']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

then you can print the URL, create html link or redirect to that new URL using header

```
header('Location: ' . $data);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$myUrl="http://test.com";
$shortUrl=file_get_contents("http://mee.la/api.php?url=".$myUrl);
echo  $shortUrl;
```

Comment: You should be using urlencode($myUrl)

Answer (score 2):

```
First Way
    echo file_get_contents('http://mee.la/api.php?url=http://test.com/');

Second Way
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mee.la/api.php?url=http://test.com/',

    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $resp;
```